# if statements inside command

Tags: windows, batch-file

I am trying to make a if statement for a CLI i am making in batch. this is the code

```
if "%command%" == "browser"(
echo Warning, this will only change the default broswer for this session
echo What would you like the default browser to be changed to?
set /p browserdefault=
)
```

I want it to check "browserdefault" and see if it is chrome, edge or a diffrent broswer
if it is none of those it should say "error, invalid broswer."

is there any way for there to be a if statement inside of the already existing if statement? like if %browserdefault% is "chrome" start C:%username%\filepath\tochrome?

I tried many diffrent ways but none of them seems to work

Comment: sorry it isnt formmated, im not sure what happened when it was posted.

Comment: Perhaps you should search for `menu`.

Comment: I suspect you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30282784/variables-are-not-behaving-as-expected and that you need to use delayed expansion and `!browserdefault!` instead of `%browserdefault%`.

Comment: Insert a _space_ before your opening `(`…

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is right, noble and good. However, this is Windows batch. The ordinary rules of style & good taste do not apply.

You should not try to nest other statements inside a batch command. There are times this will appear to work, but (based on a number of factors, such as a poorly considered logical condition, or even different input strings!) will occasionally cause the block to fail miserably. This will set you up for a world of painful debugging.

The suggestion in the comments to search for `menu` is a good one. This should lead you to code that will have (what looks like) many unnecessary & unrelated blocks, all sprinkled with horrible `goto`s. Just... it's fine. This is Windows batch. It will work, it will be reliable. Try not to think about the style too much.

There are some example menus in this excellent Q&A:

[Menus in Batch File](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19125913/2657515)

(as noted in at least one answer there, when using the naive `if ERRORLEVEL 1`, this will actually check if the number is *equal **OR** greater than* which requires starting with a higher `ERRORLEVEL` and working down to `IF ERRORLEVEL 0`, with a `GOTO` jump for each check -- using a statement with a `%` variable such as `if "1" == "%ERRORLEVEL%"` or similar avoids this pitfall).

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the other answer this is Windows batch. I do not know a way of nested if statements.
I would use `call` statements to get rid of the nested if statements like this:

```
 :getCommand
 set /P command=Enter command: 
 call :%command%
 goto :getCommand

 :browser
 set /P browserdefault=Enter browser: 
 if not "%browserdefault%"=="chrome" if not "%browserdefault%"=="edge" echo  error, invalid broswer.
 goto :eof
```